# sharing variable between two aspx c sharp files

Tags: asp.net

in my website I have two files home.aspx and tab.aspx with code behind files home.aspx.cs and tab.aspx.cs

I have a table variable in tab.aspx.cs which needs to be sent to home.aspx.cs when I click a button on home.aspx

how can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean with "table variable"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass it in a query string or session variable.

Need some more specifics for a better answer...